# Python SQL Query into PBI

Tags: python, sql, powerbi

Can you grab information from SQL queries in python and then put that python code into PowerBi? I currently use PowerBi at work and I am doing a python course so I am curious if I could do a machine learning model with python in PowerBi.

Comment: Might I recommend you learn to write sql queries for PowerBI. Using Python as an intermediary language for this use case might unnecessarily complicate this process

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Whatever you have in SQL put it in table
Use Python cursors to get data from SQL table and put it in dataframe then truncate/drop SQL table.
Check PowerBI global options and locate Python Scripting, fill in proper directory
Go to Power BI data sources and find Python script. Use it to create whatever dataset you need. Maybe do ML inside.